# Two expansions are equal, so the partial sums are all equal (MGFs)

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

I was trying to find all of the moments for a random variable $X$ with an exponential distribution and mean $\lambda$. I ultimately showed the following:

$M_x(s)=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-s}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (s/\lambda)^k$, and given that $M_x(s)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}E[X^k]$, it follows that:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}E[X^k]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (s/\lambda)^k.$$.

After seeing my professor's solution, I see that she assumes that the terms being added are equivalent for each individual $k$, i.e. that $\frac{s^k}{k!}E[X^k]=(s/\lambda)^k$, and my question is, why must this be true?

Comment: Note that for all $s<\lambda$, the equality must hold. Take $s=0$ to get the case for $k=0$, and then divide $s$ on both sides and let $s=0$ again to get the case for $k=1$. etc.